# Is there another strategy for proving this statement?

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ iff $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $\exists (a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in A$ s.t. $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \alpha$

The definition of dense that I use is: Given two sets $X, Y \subset \mathbb{R}$, with $X \subset Y$, we say that $X$ is dense in $Y$ if $Y \subset \overline{X}$

**My attempt**

($\implies$) If $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, we have that $\mathbb{R} \subseteq \overline{A}$. Taking any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, we have that $\alpha \in \overline{X}$ since $\mathbb{R} \subseteq \overline{A}$. If $\alpha \in \overline{A}$, by the definition of closure, $\alpha$ is a limit point of $A$, and therefore, there exists a sequence $(a_n)$ in $A$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \alpha$, by the definition of a limit point. As $\alpha$ was chosen arbitrarily, we can conclude that $\mathbb{R} \subseteq \overline{A}$ $\implies \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}, \exists (a_n)$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \alpha$.

($\Longleftarrow$) If for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a sequence $(a_n) \in A$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \alpha$, by definition, every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ is a limit point of $A$. We have that every limit point belongs to the closure, by definition. Therefore, for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $\alpha \in \overline{A}$ implies $\mathbb{R} \subseteq \overline{A}$. $\mathbb{R} \subseteq \overline{A}$ is the definition that $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

**Doubt**

I presented a similar demonstration to my teacher, and he said that I used statements that were precisely the ones that should be proved. I interpreted that I should prove that it's a limit point, but how do I do that? Should I use another definition of a dense set?

Comment: The definition is: Given two sets $X, Y \subset \mathbb{R}$, with $X \subset Y$, we say that $X$ is dense in $Y$ if $Y \subset \overline{X}$

Comment: I really want my proof to be clearer, that's why I'm posting it here. Any suggestions on how I can improve it?

Answer (score 2):

**Definition**

Let $(M,d_{M})$ be a metric space and $X\subseteq M$. We say that $x\in M$ is an adherent point of $X$ iff for all every $\varepsilon > 0$, there corresponds some $a\in X$ such that $d_{M}(x,a) < \varepsilon$.

**Proposition**

If $a\in M$ is an adherent point of $X$, then there exists a sequence of points $x_{n}\in X$ such that $x_{n}\to a$.

**Proof**

According to the above-mentioned definition, for every $\varepsilon = 1/n$, there corresponds some $x_{n}\in X$ such that $d_{M}(x_{n},a) < 1/n$. According to the squeeze theorem, one concludes that $x_{n}\to a$.

**Solution**

Let us prove the direction $(\Rightarrow)$ first.

Suppose that $M = \mathbb{R}$ and $\overline{X} = \mathbb{R}$. This means that every point $a\in\mathbb{R}$ is an adherent point of $X$. Consequently, due to the propostion above, there corresponds a sequence $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ satisfying $x_{n}\in X$ and $x_{n}\to a$.

Let us now prove the converse direction ($\Leftarrow$).

We need to prove that $\overline{X} = \mathbb{R}$. Since $\overline{X}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, it remains to prove $\mathbb{R}\subseteq\overline{X}$. In order to do so, consider an arbitrary element $a\in\mathbb{R}$. According to the hypothesis, there exists a sequence $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of elements in $X$ such that $x_{n}\to a$. In other words, one has that:

\begin{align*}
(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists n_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{N})(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})(n\geq n_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow |x_{n} - a| < \varepsilon)
\end{align*}

But what does it tell us?

This means that, no matter which $\varepsilon > 0$ one chooses, there corresponds $x_{n_{\varepsilon}}\in X$ so that $|x_{n_{\varepsilon}} - a| < \varepsilon$, which is precisely the definition of adherent point, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!